# Multi controller config problems in Windows 10 and in particular on Steam games?

Tags: steam, controllers, windows, windows-10

I have 2 [Mayflash F300 Arcade Fight Stick Joysticks](http://www.mayflash.com/Products/XBOXXBOX360/F300.html) and 2 [Mayflash PS2 PS3 PC USB Universal Arcade Fighting Stick Joysticks](http://www.mayflash.com/Products/PCUSB/PC042.html).  Usually these work relatively well for MAME and I can make them work fairly well with other games via [JoyToKey](http://joytokey.net) (especially games like BroForce where one keyboard can be arranged to control four players at once).

Unfortunately when I play other Steam games I'm having serious problems getting them to work properly when there is not a single-keyboard-for-multiple-players support.  For example, with `Lovers in a Dangerous Spacetime`, it worked great the first time, but then the next day when we fired it up, we can only get 3 players to work (2 controllers and 1 keyboard).  One controller will not work at all (seems to be player 2 usually for some reason even when it is different joysticks) and another joystick disallows full functionality (for example the left movement will not work).

Similar difficult behavior is fairly common across the board with other games.  We have been down the road and back here with unplugging them and attempting to reconfigure Steam controller support.  I don't see a way to reset Steam's controller settings back which I think could help, but I'm not sure.

Further when we unplug and plug the controllers back in, Windows always changes the controller order and thus we have to reconfigure MAME each time, which is a huge problem.

Are there any tools that bring some sanity to Windows controller configuration such as locking in a device as a specific controller number in Windows each time?  Are there ways to reset Steam controller settings?  Any other ideas?

Comment: Do these joysticks support DInput or XInput? You might try adding them to Steam configuration using Big Picture Mode then and customize the controls to resemble the ones on X360/One gamepad then probably.